# SQL Phpadmin- Subtract Current Date from Date Column stored in database and Stored in another column

Tags: mysql

I am using phpmyadmin for my database I am trying to   Subtract Current Date from Date Column stored in database named 'datesub' and display it to column named 'dateresult' table named 'TableA'

```
  Current Date : today


   TableA

   id            datesub            dateresult
  11111         07-11-2018
  22222         07-12-2018

 ----------------------------------------

  My Desire Output

 TableA

   id            datesub            dateresult
  11111         07-11-2018             4
  22222         07-12-2018             3


 My Sql Query is 

 SELECT DATEDIFF(year, 'Today', datesub) AS dateresult;
```

however it is not working I am getting error

```
 MySQL said: Documentation

 #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

I would really appreciate help and advice thank you in advance

Comment: `DATEDIFF` in `MySQL` accept two parameters, and in `SQL Server` accept three parameters,you need to check your database type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), datesub)
FROM TableA
```

Sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db690/3).